# Sql to repeat rows for all the months based on Startdate and EndDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table 'Quota' Which has Quota Amount for every team with Start Date and End Date of quota's. Here is the sample quota Table

[image]

'StartDate' is Start date of quota, 'StartMonthYear' is month+Year of startdate, 'EndDate' is end date of quota , 'QuotaAmount' is quota between startdate and EndDate and TeamName is Team Name for which this Quota assigned to.

Now I how can i generate repeated rows of a particular Quota on monthly basis?
Sample output i am looking for is

[image]

Here Team T1 is having quota for 3 months so i want 3 different records for each month with start date as month start date and 'End date' as Month End Date.

Note : Quotas always start from 1 day of month and end at last day of month.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My recommendation is to simplify this for yourself by placing the "logic" to do this in a stored procedure. My sense is that doing this in a a single SQL query would be unnecessarily cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a calendar table, you can use a TVF which generates dynamic date/time ranges

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2016-01-01'  -- These could be a query for min/max dates
Declare @Date2 date = '2016-12-31' 

Select A.StartDate
      ,StartMonthYear = month(A.StartDate)*10000+Year(A.StartDate)
      ,A.EndDate
      ,B.QuotaAmount
      ,B.TeamName
 From (Select StartDate=RetVal,EndDate=DateAdd(DD,-1,DateAdd(MM,1,RetVal)) From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](@Date1,@Date2,'MM',1)) A
 Join YourTable B
   on A.StartDate between B.StartDate and B.EndDate
 Order by TeamName,A.StartDate
```

Returns

[image]

The UDF if Needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```